# How to use a package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use this package https://github.com/AbdullahGhanem/rating. I am having trouble while using it. I have installed the package.I want to know where should I place this code `$post->averageRating()` and I have created rating in Controller. Is that the right way to do?

Here is my layout code:

```
<html>
<head>
</style>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <header><h3>Comments</h3></header>
        <form action="/comments" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" rows="5" placeholder="Your review on above game"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post  Comment</button>

        </form>
    </div>
  </div>



    @foreach($comments as $comment) 
<h1>{{$comment->body }}</h1>
@endforeach

{{$post->averageRating();}}
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Controllers code:-

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;




class CommentsController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    $comments = comment::all();
    $post=Post::all();
return view('comments.create', ['comments' => $comments]);


}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $comment= new Comment();
    $comment->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->body=$request->body;
    $comment->save();
    return back();

  $user = User::first();
  $post = Post::first();

  $rating = $post->rating([
  'rating' => 5
   ], $user);

 dd($rating);

 }

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show()
{
    //

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}


}
```

here is my model code :-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Ghanem\Rating\Contracts\Rating;
use Ghanem\Rating\Traits\Ratingable as RatingTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model implements Rating
{
//


use RatingTrait;
}
```

here is the code in web.php:-

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
//comments
Route::resource('comments','CommentsController');
//like
Route::post('/like', [
'uses' => 'LikeController@postLikePost',
'as' => 'like'
]);
```

code in my app.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
| framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
| any other location as required by the application or its packages.
*/

'name' => 'Laravel',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
| running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
| services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
|
*/

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloaded Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
| request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
| this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    //

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Ghanem\Rating\RatingServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

],

];
```

thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Any issues with packages consult right in "issue tracker" of package on GitHub, you will most likely get answer faster + on point.

Comment: for that the person who made the package should be active which he isn't.

Comment: In that case move and use different package since this one may be buggy already...

Comment: do you know any good working package?It can be related to like/dislike or rating functionality.

Comment: Maybe this https://packagist.org/packages/willvincent/laravel-rateable

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that the `Trait` works, you can call it anytime on any model that has an existing rating. If the rating does not exist, it will return `null`. You can create the `rating` in your Controller, which is completely fine.

So, inside of a view, you may call:

```
{{ $post->averageRating() }}
```

and it will return you the `averageRating` for that particular post.

Your model needs to implement the `Ratingable` factory.

```
class Post extends Model implements Ratingable
```

You are currently implementing `Rating which is incorrect.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to import my models.Now I am getting this error Interface 'Ghanem\Rating\Contracts\Rating' not found this means there is a problem  that package right?

Comment: bcz I using importing this Ghanem\Rating\Contracts\Rating'  as said in read me in post model

Comment: @Pawan This usually means you haven't booted the packages service provider. Open up `config/app.php` locate the `packages` section and paste in the ` Ghanem\Rating\RatingServiceProvider::class` package.

Comment: I did added it have look at desription i am editing the description and adding code in app.php

Comment: do you still have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: could it be importing issue?